# i am getting blank response using commentid/comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am applying new changes for my application,when i am fetching comment replies of comments.
I am getting blank response.
http://graph.facebook.com/commentid/comments

Comment: No such http://graph.api domain exist

Comment: I have added graph api for just reference.

Comment: It most likely a bug, you may report it on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Yup, i have reported facebook as bug, but still i am waiting response from facebook api team side.I am very disappoint from facebook api support team.http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/562760033755005?browse=search_517e147987e825619979735

Comment: No, they fixed my reported bug within 3 days https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/447161155374499?browse=search_517e2464843ff8636710929, i'm quite satisfied :)

Comment: One more thing about the bug you report, COMMENT_ID should be 455859557777297_608134589216459_112978460, not 608134589216459_112978460. even though i'm not sure what's the different of them, however you would get "id":455859557777297_608134589216459_112978460 when you call http://graph.facebook.com/455859557777297_608134589216459

Comment: thanks, i had tried both types of id,but i was not success.

Answer (score 0):

For temporary solution, do this way:

```
SELECT post_id, id, fromid, time, text, user_likes, likes FROM comment WHERE parent_id='COMMENT_ID' LIMIT 30
```

You require to **enable the July 2013 Migration** on your app advanced settings, to use the parent_id column. Example here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOU_APP_ID/advanced

More info, please visit https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Comment: i had tried with below SQL "SELECT post_id, id, fromid, time, text, user_likes, likes FROM comment WHERE parent_id='pageid_608134589216459_112978460' LIMIT 30" but i am getting exception from facebook "{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#602) parent_id is not a member of the comment table.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 602
  }
}"

Comment: You need to enable "July 2013 Breaking Changes" radio button on your app advanced settings. And the parent id is the comment id. You should test with the comment id which was get from http://graph.facebook.com/POSDT_ID/comments, to make sure the comment id is correct.